# Compare two arrays to get the next value of one array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the next value of another array.

```
var books = ["book1", "book3"];
var bookprice = [["book1", "$5"], ["book2", "$2"], ["book3", "$7"]];
var list = [];

for (key in bookprice) {
    if(bookprice.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        list.push(bookprice[key][0]);
    }
}   

list = ["book1", "book2", "book3"];
```

so when I search for `book1` then it returns `$5`.
I am stuck on the next step what I need to do. Do I need to `filter` to get the index of each first?

Comment: `bookprice` should really be an object. That's what objects are use for.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir is there an example to achieve simple thing by using an object? Thanks

Comment: I'll post an answer. Wait!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now as you have got the list you can use `Array.find()` to find the inner array with that book name and then get the second element which is the price using `[1]` on the `find()` result.

**Using `Array.find()`**

```js
var bookprice = [
  ["book1", "$5"],
  ["book2", "$2"],
  ["book3", "$7"]
];

var list = ["book1", "book2", "book3"];
var bookName = list[0];
var price = bookprice.find(innerArray => innerArray[0] === bookName)[1];
console.log(price);
```

**FOR IE (pure JS)**

```js
var bookprice = [
  ["book1", "$5"],
  ["book2", "$2"],
  ["book3", "$7"]
];

var list = ["book1", "book2", "book3"];
var bookName = list[0];
var price;
for(var i=0; i<bookprice.length; i++){
  if(bookprice[i][0] === bookName){
    price = bookprice[i][1];
    break;
  }
}
console.log(price);
```

Comment: Just a note. If the OP did use an object here, they could call `['bookPrice']` in place of `[1]` on the second to last line.

Comment: Thanks, is there a pure JavaScript method can be used? I found `Array.find()` is not working for IE, I need at least IE11

Comment: @olo you can use the simple function instead of arrow function in IE. Updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Using `Array.find` and `destructuration`

```js
const bookprice = [
  ['book1', '$5'],
  ['book2', '$2'],
  ['book3', '$7'],
];

const list = ['book1', 'book2', 'book3'];

const bookName = list[0];

const [
  ,
  price,
] = bookprice.find(([
  name,
  price,
]) => name === bookName);

console.log(price);
```

---

Also as someone already told you in the comment, best would be to create an object and not an array of array.

```js
const bookprice = {
  book1: '$5',
  book2: '$2',
  book3: '$7',
};

const list = ['book1', 'book2', 'book3'];

const bookName = list[0];

const price = bookprice[bookName];

console.log(price);
```

---

**Compatible IE 11**

```js
var bookprice = [
  ['book1', '$5'],
  ['book2', '$2'],
  ['book3', '$7'],
];

var list = ['book1', 'book2', 'book3'];

var bookName = list[0];

var price;

for (var i = 0; i < bookprice.length && price === void 0; i += 1) {
  if (bookprice[i][0] === bookName) {
     price = bookprice[i][1];
  }
}

console.log(price);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var bookprice = [["book1", "$5"], ["book2", "$2"], ["book3", "$7"]];

var list = ["book1", "book2", "book3"];
var bookName = list[0];
var price = bookprice[list.indexOf(bookName)][1];
console.log(price);
```

Answer (score 1):

If `bookprice` was an object, retrieving the price of a particular book would be an easy thing to do. `bookprice` should be:

```
var bookprice = {
    "book1": "$5", 
    "book2": "$2",
    "book3": "$7"
};
```

Then retireieving the price of a book will be as easy and simple as:

```
var book = "book1";
var price = bookprice[book];
```

#### Transforming `bookprice` into an object:

**Using a `for` loop (for old browsers):**

```
var bookpriceObject = {};
for(var i = 0; i < bookprice.length; i++) {
    bookpriceObject[bookprice[i][0]] = bookprice[i][1];
}
```

**Using `reduce`:**

```
var bookpriceObject = bookprice.reduce(function(acc, book) {
    acc[book[0]] = book[1];
    return acc;
}, {});
```

which can be shortened using an arrow function:

```
var bookpriceObject = bookprice.reduce((acc, book) => (acc[book[0]] = book[1], acc), {});
```

Comment: Thanks! I wanted to use an object. I was unable to loop through `bookprice` `var books = ["book1", "book3"];
var bookprice = [["book1", "$5"], ["book2", "$2"], ["book3", "$7"]];
var list = {};
for (var i = 0; i <bookprice.length; i++) {
 list = {
  bookprice[i][0]: bookprice[i][1];
    }
}`

Comment: @olo I didn't get that. Can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: Sorry, wasn't clear. I was trying to make an object the way you showed here, but didn't didn't succeed

Comment: @olo Can you please show me what went wrong? This should have worked as expected?

Comment: The code pasted above,  Could you please let me know how do you cover  `var bookprice = [["book1", "$5"], ["book2", "$2"], ["book3", "$7"]];` to an object `var bookprice = {
    "book1": "$5", 
    "book2": "$2",
    "book3": "$7"
};` Many thanks

Comment: @olo the best way to do that is to just do it manually (redesign so that `bookprice` is an object). If you have no control over that, then just use the solution from the accepted answer, or transform the array using the methods from my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use Array.find as https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

```js
var bookprice = [
  ["book1", "$5"],
  ["book2", "$2"],
  ["book3", "$7"]
];

function getBookPrice(bookname) {
    let book = bookprice.find(item => item[0] === bookname)
    if (book) {
        return book[1];
    } else {
        console.log('No book Found');
        return 0;
    }
}

console.log(getBookPrice('book1'));
console.log(getBookPrice('book2'));
console.log(getBookPrice('book3'));
console.log(getBookPrice('randombook'));
```